# How do I add a constraint such that a view is as wide as the widest of two other views?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, autolayout

For example, labels A, B and C. Label A should have the width of whichever is wider, B or C.

Visually, something along the lines of

```
@"H:[viewA(==MAX(viewB,viewC))]"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Autolayout height equal to MAX(multiple view heights)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17117799/autolayout-height-equal-to-maxmultiple-view-heights)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ensure that `viewA` is simultaneously at least as wide as both `viewB` and `viewC`, then use two separate VFL statements, `@"H:[viewA(>=viewB)]"` and `@"H:[viewA(>=viewC)]"`.

If you also want to ensure that A will not be wider than the maximum width of `viewB` and/or `viewC`, you would define an optional constraint (i.e. lower priority than `UILayoutPriorityRequired`) for the width of `viewA` to be equal to one of them, e.g.:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:viewA
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:viewB
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                             multiplier:1.0
                                                               constant:0.0];
constraint.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow;
[viewA.superview addConstraint:constraint];
```

According to the documentation for [`priority`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/NSLayoutConstraint/NSLayoutConstraint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010628-CH1-SW19):

> If a constraint 'a == b' is optional, the constraint-based layout system will attempt to minimize 'abs(a-b)'.

Thus, if `viewB` is larger than `viewC`, this optional constraint will be satisfied and `viewA` will be as wide as `viewB`. If `viewB` is smaller than `viewC`, the constraint system will satisfy the required `@"H:[viewA(>=viewC)]"` constraint, but then will also minimize the `abs(a-b)`, effectively making `viewA` the same width as `viewC`.

In practice, you probably don't need this optional `viewA==viewB` constraint, but if you want to ensure that `viewA` won't be wider than both `viewB` and `viewC`, then add this final optional constraint.