# AutoLayout - equal heights based on taller view

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, autolayout

*This is conceptually similar to [Autolayout height equal to MAX(multiple view heights)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17117799/autolayout-height-equal-to-maxmultiple-view-heights) except that question is sizing a container view, but I am wanting both buttons to be sized to the height of the maximum height button.*

---

I have two buttons that are side-by-side in a footer section of a view. I want the buttons to be the same width, so I applied a constraint to make them the same width and that works fine. I also want them to the the same height, in case one of the buttons ends up taking more than one line for its title. I tried setting the heights of both buttons the same, but when I do that, the button that is shorter always is used when determining the height for both buttons. For example, if the first button is just one line of text and the second button is three lines of text, then both buttons will be sized for just one line of text. The same thing happens if the text is swapped so that the first button is supposed to be taller.

I have set the content hugging and compression resistance priorities for both buttons too, but that still doesn't seem to help, or I am setting them wrong.

```objectivec
[self->_firstButton setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
[self->_firstButton setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
        
[self->_firstButton setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
[self->_firstButton setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
```

And the same priorities are set for the second button.

Here are the constraints that make both buttons the same size and these do work as the buttons are the same width and they are the same height, but again the problem is that the height is the height of the shorter button (the button with a shorter title text).

```objectivec
[self.firstButton.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.secondButton.heightAnchor],
[self.firstButton.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.secondButton.widthAnchor]
```

Does anyone see what I might be doing wrong? Or does anyone know how to fix this so that both buttons will be the height of the taller button (the button with a longer title) and not the height of the button with a shorter title?

Comment: *"the second button is three lines of text"* -- what code are you using to allow three lines of text in the button? Or, are you using the new iOS 15 style button?

Comment: @DonMag It is actually a custom UIControl subclass that implements the functionality of a button. Inside the custom button class the title is just a label with the numberOfLines set to zero by default and the text will wrap to multiple lines and the button will expand in height if it's width is constrained (which it is in this case since each button is roughly half of the width of the containing superview). It is similar to the new iOS 15 button in concept, except I need to be able to support iOS 13+.

Comment: @DonMag (continued, 2 of 3) For this question, however, we could even change it so that instead of equal sized buttons, we could be talking about equal sized labels because that is really the same problem. Basically, I just am not sure how to make it so that two labels (or any view really) with differing heights are the height of the tallest view. So if one label (or button) has one line and the other has three lines, I would like the shorter view to be sized such that it is the same height as the taller view, that way they are both the same height and no content is lost.

Comment: @DonMag (continued, 3 of 3) I have thought about overriding `layoutSubviews` and then in there setting the height of the two views to be the height of the taller view (I think all the frame heights are available in this method, or if there is a better method where all the frame sizes are known, please let me know). I think something like this would work, but I was just wanting to see if there was a better way of doing it or a way of using AutoLayout to calculate the max heights of both of the subviews. Anyway, thank you for your help and please let me know if anything is unclear. Thanks again.

Comment: Sounds like your custom control is messing with auto-layout. This quick sample code: https://pastebin.com/Y3WEhGrL using two labels in a stack view, results in this output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LazGG.png

Comment: @DonMag Thanks so much for your help here. I will try to wrap the views in a stack view. I am still curious how stack view implements these constraints such that both labels are the height of the maximum height label. What you have implemented is exactly what I want, I was just trying to do it without the stack view. But I will try to implement it this way to see if it fixes things. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry - thought you were using a stack view (why not?). If you really don't want to, you cannot do it without run-time code calculating the heights of your two controls and then setting constraints to match the tallest one. The other option is to embed them in a view, and constrain the tops and bottoms... the taller one will make the view taller, which will stretch the height of the shorter one.

Comment: @DonMag The issue was inside the custom button class. I had a content hugging priority of required for the label vertically. But what I don't understand is that I have the following constraints: `label.top >= button.layoutMargins.top` && `label.bottom <= button.layoutMargins.bottom`, so I was thinking that even if the label was not allowed to stretch vertically, the button should still be able to stretch since those constraints are inequality constraints. Apparently this is incorrect because once I removed the hugging priority, everything started working, but do you know why that is? Thanks.

Comment: @DonMag Sorry about the previous comment. I figured out what was wrong there too. I have different configurations of the button class (image, text, image and text, ...) and I was looking at one configuration which had the inequality constraints but the configuration I was using here had equality constraints. So I guess that answers that question and now the heights are working. I do have one other question but it is unrelated. It is a question about the target-action not always getting called if the button is placed within certain other views. But I can open a new question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comments were not quite correct...

***IF*** you have properly set constraints inside your custom view / control, or if you're setting its intrinsic size correctly, you can get the desired result with very few constraints... even if the views are not contained in a stack view or other "container" view.

For example, this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    UILabel *v1 = [UILabel new];
    v1.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];
    v1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    v1.numberOfLines = 0;
    v1.text = @"One Line";
    
    UILabel *v2 = [UILabel new];
    v2.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    v2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    v2.numberOfLines = 0;
    v2.text = @"Lots of text to force the label to wrap onto multiple lines.";

    for (UIView *v in @[v1, v2]) {
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:v];
    }
    
    UILayoutGuide *g = [self.view safeAreaLayoutGuide];

    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        
        [v1.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.leadingAnchor constant:20.0],
        [v2.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.trailingAnchor constant:-20.0],
        
        [v1.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.bottomAnchor constant:-20.0],
        [v2.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.bottomAnchor constant:-20.0],

        [v1.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:v2.widthAnchor],
        [v2.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:v1.trailingAnchor constant:20.0],
        
        [v1.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:v2.heightAnchor],
        
    ]];
    
    // not striclty needed, but to make sure they don't compress
    [v1 setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
    [v2 setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
}
```

produces this result:

[image]

and, by changing **only the text** in the two labels:

[image]

Comment: Thanks again for your help troubleshooting this.